# Create object by for loop

Tags: javascript

I have a code like this:

```
 var HardCodeObject = {
  title: "Customers",
  rows: [
    {
      cells: [
        { value: "Company Name" },
        { value: "Contact" }
      ]
    },
    {
      cells: [
        { value: "Around the Horn" },
        { value: "Thomas Hardy" }
      ]
    },
    {
      cells: [
        { value: "B's Beverages" },
        { value: "Victoria Ashworth" }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

How create this object by for loop in Cells object?

i try this code but not work :

```
var cells = [];
var value = new Array();
value.push("a");
value.push("b");
cells.push(value);
var value = new Array();
value.push("a");
value.push("b");
cells.push(value);
var value = new Array();
value.push("a");
value.push("b");
cells.push(value);
var d = new Object();
d.title = "Customer";
d.rows = cells;
```

it is for export to excel in kendo UI.

Comment: You should not be using the `var` keyword repeatedly, as you can only use it one time in each lexical environment. Anywhere you have `var value = new Array();`, except for the first time, you need to replace it with just `value = new Array();`

Comment: Consider using one way to make an array. [] or “new Array”. I prefer the first way.

Comment: Always use `var obj = {}; var arr = [];` format in JavaScript and keep it consistent. I have also added a guided answer for you. Please check it out as well.

Comment: @Samathingamajig I have used your comment reference in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome!
I would like to point out that your first `cells` seems to be column headers, so, in a `<table>`, they would be `<th>`s and in `<thead>`, and the rest would be `<td>`s and in `<tbody>`.
So, `HardCodeObject` could look like this: `{title: "Customers", fields:["Company Name", "Contact"], data:[["Around the Horn", "Thomas Hardy"], ["B's Beverages", "Victoria Ashworth"]]}`.

Comment: @iAmOren Good thought...

Answer (score 1):

There's a much better way to achieve this one. First off, as [Samathingamajig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12101554/samathingamajig) said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64517121/create-object-by-for-loop#comment114080583_64517121), don't reuse `var` keyword repeatedly.

For this answer, I am assuming or asking you to make the contents of the rows in a multidimensional `Elements` array in this form:

```js
var Elements = [
  ["Company Name", "Contact"],              // Row 1
  ["Around the Horn", "Thomas Hardy"],      // Row 2
  ["B's Beverages", "Victoria Ashworth"]    // Row 3
];
```

And secondly, understanding the JavaScript basics will help you a lot. Let me add a guided answer here:

```js
// Create a new object by using an Object Literal.
var CodedObject = {};
// Set the title.
CodedObject.title = "Customers";
// Initialise rows with an empty array.
CodedObject.rows = [];
// Let's think of a couple of elements in a 2D Array.
var Elements = [
  ["Company Name", "Contact"],              // Row 1
  ["Around the Horn", "Thomas Hardy"],      // Row 2
  ["B's Beverages", "Victoria Ashworth"]    // Row 3
];
// Now let's use a loop to create objects based on the elements.
// Also, let's define a single Row Object.
var row = {};
for (var i = 0; i < Elements.length; i++) {
  // Reset the row object for every iteration.
  row = {
    cells: []
  };
  // Add the two values using a loop now.
  for (var r = 0; r < Elements[i].length; r++) {
    // Add cell value.
    row.cells.push({
      value: Elements[i][r]
    });
  }
  // Push the row value.
  CodedObject.rows.push(row);
}

// Let's see if this works.
console.log(CodedObject);
```

I get the output for the above program like this:

```
{
  "title": "Customers",
  "rows": [
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": "Company Name"
        },
        {
          "value": "Contact"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": "Around the Horn"
        },
        {
          "value": "Thomas Hardy"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cells": [
        {
          "value": "B's Beverages"
        },
        {
          "value": "Victoria Ashworth"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to do something like this:

```js
const rows = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    rows.push({
        cells: [{
            value: "a"
        }, {
            value: "b"
        }]
    });
}

const obj = {
    title: "Customer",
    rows: rows
};

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: You can also do `rows` instead of `rows: rows` in the new ES6 approach supported by the browsers too.

Comment: Indeed, quite a useful shortcut but it's one more detail to learn so I left it verbose (since javad daryabari appears to be a novice programmer).

Comment: Oh yes, I get that Rocky, if you knew it then cool. It's just for you.  I didn't mean to change the answer. I was just telling there's an alternate.